# In search of a good and customisable IDE, Is eclipse is the ultimate one?

Tags: xml, eclipse, ide, kate

I am using GNU/Linux (Ubuntu + Gnome).

I have been using netbeans on windows since a long time and on Linux I prefer to use vi or emacs.

Now my problem is I want to totally migrate into Linux for all my development works but i have seen that netbeans do not has that appealing look as it used to have on windows. Same with eclipse. I know looks doesnot matters but when i look at native Linux apps like kedit, geany IDE they have a sturdy and a good look.. i guess nobody has made such a comment on IDEs but i feels looks also matters.. :)

I have used vi for editing configuration files and writing small programs but when it comes to writing a big project then i *guess* vi is not that effective (I have no idea how much vi plugins are effective.)

Now there are several options for selecting an IDE but i want to use one on which i can depend on for a long run (if i try each and every IDE on this earth then when will i write my code).

Out of all IDEs and Text Editors i have ever used, i liked kate a lot.. is it possible to customize kate to have feature an IDE has.. like version control support, code completion, a proper project explorer window on the left hand side. I have seen a Latex IDE "kile" which has integrated kate into it.. does any IDE exists with kate integrated into it? is it possible to have vi key binding support on kate..

Or should i keep all this stuff apart and use eclipse instead (for me it seems to be quite difficult to use as compared to netbeans but will it work well for editing files of different languages at once like html files, css files, js files, xml files and some python code.. and worth learning "how to use eclipse")?

I work on HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Python, PHP(not that often), XUL(An XML for Firefox GUI), bash scripting. As you can see that i am extremely with IDE selection, please suggest me some thing (an IDE or text editor with enough tweaks) so that I can use it for all different languages/files i use at once with code completion and syntax highlighting features.

Comment: Looks is all what you care? Not Productivity .. 
-1

Comment: Short Answer, Yes they do matter.
Long Answer, I ended up using Emacs, reason being the set of awesome key bindings which came natural to me, and the minimalistic UI. It was painful to use Eclipse on Linux (with 10' screens, unfortunately which was the only computer I could afford at that time), on dialog boxes, if things hide due to less space, there is no scroll bar to access it, plus it was super slow. For automation, which IDEs are good at, I have written some in-house scripts and use flymake where ever possible. Eclipse might be awesome for some people but for me, it was very repulsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have only used Eclipse on Windows and Solaris, I have never noticed any differences in looks, and definitely not in functionality. Friends who've used it on various linux builds (admittedly mostly Ubuntu) also seems to have the same GUI as I do - at least from what I can discern from looking over their shoulders :P

But from my experience, Eclipse is more than enough for handling all web client code ((x)html, css, javascript...), some web server code (mainly php, but I would assume both jsp and python scripted pages work as well), as well as several desktop/script languages (I've happily used Eclipse for both Java and python development - python requires a free plugin, but works as a charm).

You get syntax highlighting, code completion (a.k.a. intellisense), build and debug functionality, project explorer, probably version control - if not built-in, then I'm sure there are plugins for it, packaging and publishing options...

In short, I think Eclipse is a great tool for developing in all the languages you mentioned.

Comment: the difference in appearance is for netbeans. that looks different in gtk/qt environment ac compared to .net environment.
eclipse dont look that appealing to me. ( personal opinion )

eclipse is an excellent ide but i never know which plugin to install and how they works(how to activate and use them)..
when i look at the available plugin list then i can see many plugins with the same name with a little difference in them..
"It might be because i dont understand how eclipse is build"

I guess eclipse is very powerful but I am unable to harness it.

any suggestions you want to give for that!

Comment: @Idlecool: Coming from the realm of .NET and Visual Studio, I too found Eclipse rather ugly and hard to grasp. But after working on a few Java projects for school I got used to it, and now I happily use it for anything that's not .NET or web (simply because for the web I have VS...). As far as plugins go, I have really only used PyDev for python programming, but it works really well. A list of available python plugins for Eclipse can be found here: http://wiki.python.org/moin/EclipsePythonIntegration And if you have questions about plugins for other things, you can always ask here at SO =)

Comment: okay! gr8!! :) i have loaded my eclipse with all sorts of plugins! now uninstalled every third party plugin and installing pydev as fresh.. this time i gotta get into it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try KDevelop: http://www.kdevelop.org/

Comment: Can't say anything about KDevelop's qualities as an IDE but KDE applications tend to integrate poorly into GNOME. Since looks are what the OP cares about (as silly as it is) this might not be the best suggestion. Which is sad because many KDE applications are superior to their GNOME counterparts. And I say this as a die-hard GNOME user.

Comment: @musikk gnome is simple,stable and awesome.. i love it....
I agree that kde apps are superior to gnome, but i get what ever i need from gnome apps only.. the only ide thing i was worried of but
seems i gonna convince myself with eclipse, its really powerful :)

@Protostome: kdevelop is a powerful one but i want to go for eclipse this time :)

Comment: Well, given the sluggish nature of eclipse (and Java applications in particular, if I might add..) the KDevelop option, ran on gnome with all the necessary kde libs is a better one... And that's from first hand. But this is just my personal opinion... :-)

Comment: Only if Kdevelop supports python :(  . it is an awesome IDE , just without python support

Answer (score 0):

I really like JetBrain's IDEs. They're plugin-based and they have a version for HTML/js/css, python, PHP, and of course Java.  And there's lots of plugins available.